# How to get a value from Jade to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, passport.js

I know this looks repetitive, but it is a little bit different than the other question here.

I am using Node with the expressJS routing and passportJS login and in my login page I have a dropdown list to select a value that I want to pass along to my Angular script.

In my app.js I have:

```
var languages = [
   {"lang": "English", "code": "en"},
   {"lang": "Chinese", "code": "zh-cn"}
];
app.get('/', detectBrowser, routes.index);
app.get('/login', routes.login(isSameSubnet, languages));
```

index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { login: 'Some String' });
};

exports.login = function(language) {
   return function(req, res) {
       res.render('login', { lang: language });
   };
};
```

login.jade:

```
label.control-label Language
select.form-control
    each val, index in lang
       option(value= val.code)= val.lang
```

So how can I grab the value of the option tag back to my javascript and pass it to the next stage (AngularJS)?

I know how to get the information from the **exports.index** on the Angular side, but I don't know how to get the information I want and use it on this index function.

Thanks

Comment: You do it in JavaScript, start by assigning a unique id to the select so you can find in Angular

Comment: But the angular support comes right after this login screen, so I can't "see" the select when the angular app has started.

Comment: you have to post it with the login info (username and password).